# How to create Android UI library

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-library

I have so many util codes for UI and want to create a android library for each of them. With all my research I have done below things.

- File -> new module. Create an android library
- in build.gradle file implement the library `implementation project(':app:FirstLibrary')`
- Kotlin and xml file in library is below

```
FirstLib.kt

class FirstLib(mContext: Context) : Activity() {
    private var mContext: Context? = null
    private var view: View? = null

    fun s(message: String?) {
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.first_lib_view, null)
        Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

```
first_lib_view.xml 

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Om Namah Shivaya"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

- Next, I'm trying to access this UI library in main xml file like below

```
<com.example.firstlibrary.FirstLib
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools="ajkdfbj"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Now I'm not getting anything. Even toast message was not coming.

How to create UI library in Android and use it. I have my own custom video players, audio players, image gradient views etc. I need to make all those libraries now. Thanks for reading

Comment: hello, I think your main problem is you're trying to add activity at xml level. Inherit you class from `Fragment` or start activity in a usual way

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin Any kotlin tutorial ? I'm a not advance developer just a newbie. Kindly show some code with explanation.

Comment: yeah, of course) but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin I have custom exoplayer where i added volume and brigthness control by gesture. Now i want to make it as a separate library.

Comment: and this one ui is a separate window, isnt it?

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin I didn't get you ! I want mycustomexoplayer in main_activity.xml with other components.

Comment: but what is `mycustomexoplayer`? is it a custom view, or custom fragment or custom activity?

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin it is `custom view` with ` custom activity`. Same as in example but with lot of codes.

Comment: so, then put this custom activity at separate module (as you did already) and call this activity with `startActivity(Intent(context, MyCustomActivity::class.java))` or declare it as entry point at your manifest

Comment: currently, you just put `FirstLib`, which is not a view, into `xml` file. it will not work that way

Comment: do i need to put `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` this code in library manifest ?

Comment: yeah, if you want it this activity to be an entry point at the whole application. `Launcher` stands for an entry point

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin If possible kindly write the answer on how to write a simple textview as library. So that i'll learn it and implement the same to my customExoplayer.

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin Kindly write the answer in Kotlin coz I never had a chance to learn Java.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a custom view element you need to put your class into the separate module as you did before and inherit your custom view from a view.

- Ie if it's a custom view and you expect to use it inside `xml` files then you should create smth like:

```
MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
): View {

// you should override onMeasure, onLayout, onDraw here as it marked as abstract afaik

// and implement your logic

}
```

and implement the whole `onMeasure`, `onLayout`, `onDraw` logic.

- If you want to extend the existing view logic, then just inherit it from the existing one and hatch behaviour.

```
MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
): TextView() {

... your logic goes here...

}
```

You did implement a custom activity but uses it like a view, so, that's why it doesnt work for you

PS: [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) you can find out more about custom view components

Comment: Now, How to use it in `main_activity.xml` ?

Comment: the same way as you did before

Comment: you CAN declare custom view inside of xml 

Comment: Ok, I'm trying this once I achieved I'll mark it as answer. Now i gave thumbs up thank you.

Comment: What is `MyCustomView` is it class. Where to put the above code ?

Comment: Yeah , it’s class

Comment: I would eliminate the `defStyleAttr` parameter and call the two-parameter super-constructor, so the custom view can properly inherit styles from the current theme.

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin I tried in so many ways. getting `Expecting Top level declaration` can't write in the way you have written. Kindly show the complete file.

Comment: @rock The above code is missing `class` before the classname and `(context, attrs)` after `View` to call the super constructor.

Comment: @Tenfour04 if i put class it is giving error. I need detailed step by step implementation of this answer.

Comment: @AlexanderDadukin it says i can't inflate activity. Now I'm thinking to write this library using fragment. But how to start with and use it ?

Comment: Yeah, you can inflate fragment from xml, all you need to do is inherit your custom class from `Fragment`

Comment: Subclass View, not Activity.

Comment: @Tenfour04 what do you mean by Subclass View, not Activity. are you saying that the above code will work. Kindly give the complete code with a simple text view as UI. I'm very beginner with no knowledge of JAVA. And there is no recent tutorial on this topic. The only tutorial i got is 4 years old and it's not working.

Comment: You said your error says you can't inflate Activity. This is because you have subclassed Activity instead of View in your original code. If you're not sure what this means, you need to learn more fundamentals of Java or Kotlin before you can do something more advanced like making a custom view. The official documentation has instructions on how to make a custom view here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components

Comment: The example in this answer subclasses View directly, but then you have to implement all the complicated measuring and drawing logic. In the vast majority of cases, you should subclass an existing layout like FrameLayout or RelativeLayout. Or if you are simply modifying behavior of a single view like TextView, then you subclass that directly.

Comment: Yeah, @Tenfour04 absolutely right. @rock you have an option to extend from `Fragment` and use it inside of xml if you need custom composition with multiple views and business logic. For your case it would be many times easier to extend from view as you have custom player, which behaves as a single view or small view composition.